# When client open my application it get this error "hexadecimal value 0x00 is an invalid character"

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I have created an application with work fine on some pc but give this "hexadecimal value 0x00 is an invalid character" error on some pc
I find out that this exception is occur because of null values in xml.
But I haven't doing anything means get xml etc on start of application
When open the application its show the website and this error.
I don't get it why its just giving the error while opening the application
error is this

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

******* *Exception Text* *********
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 12, position 130604.

Comment: You haven't shown any context here; no problematic xml, and nothing to show what type(s) it is trying to load the data into. You don't indicate where the xml has come from. The *most likely* explanation (IMO) is: invalid xml (for example, some corrupt data in the file, leading to 0-bytes). Another thing to look at: are all clients using the same version of .NET? Is this something that has changed between .NET versions, and one client is behind on updates?

Comment: I haven't show xml here b/c I am not loading or getting XML at the start of application & error is not occuring at my site.Client have same .net frame work installed.

Comment: I've tried to edit this twice to add proper code tags and don't seem to be having any success - Someone else please have a go.

Comment: Your user.config file is broken.  A common cause for such kind of mishaps is damage inflicted on the file by hard drive errors.  You'll need to run a scan on the drive to check and repair errors.  And replacing the drive ought to be high on your list of priorities.  Ask questions about this at superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys
I found the answer

when its raises exception

I just deleted MYProject Folder under

C:\Users\\AppData\Local

Delete-->MYProject Folder

The much quicker way to access the Local Folders is to type %localappdata% in Windows Explorer and hit Enter